# Referencing mytubeid in iframe using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, scrapy

What does the `mytubeid` tag(like `<iframe src="/portal/corporateEventsCalendarIframe.html" mytubeid="mytube1" width="820" height="1600" frameborder="0"/>`) do in an `iframe`?

Note that the `iframe` do not have an `id` or as such in it!

How can it be referenced in code? I am using *python+selenium+scrapy* to build a webscraping tool.

Comment: I think `mytubeid` is an attribute not a tag under `iframe` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find  this iframe using selenium try something like

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@mytubeid="mytube1"]')`.

For more explicit answer please provide some code and site url.

Comment: Thanks @Vlad, it did help me retrieve the intended element but I was looking for something to work with `response` thingy. The [intended site](http://lankabd.com/companies/corporate-event-calendar) contains my required info inside a `iframe` and **it** further requires me to click a _link_ to reach there. I am a bit lost here with my _python+selenium+scrapy_ for data-fetching!

Comment: In order to pass url from a scrapy response to selenium, you can use `driver.get(response.url)`.
After that, you may need a switch to needed iframe `driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")` and locate link you need to click. Furter you can get a href attribute from the link using `link.get_attribute("href")`  and pass that href to scrapy or selenium. Unfortunately, without your code, it's all I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath

You can locate elements by XPath.

From website:

> One of the main reasons for using XPath is when you don’t have a suitable id or name attribute for the element you wish to locate.